# PHP codesniffer (phpcs) - how to allow override when using as part of a svn pre-commit hook?

Tags: php, svn, coding-style, pre-commit-hook, phpcodesniffer

We have a PHP 5 web application and we're currently evaluating [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) in order to decide whether forcing code standards improves code quality.

We use [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for our code repository and deployment base and I have added a SVN [pre-commit hook](http://www.google.com/search?q=phpcs-svn-pre-commit) to ensure all files committed are free from coding standard smells. The hook technically works but causes too many headaches to be actually useful:

1. If we have to fix an emergency bug that is causing a site outage, the last thing we need is the commit to be denied due to some minor whitespace indentation issue.
2. We have ALOT of legacy code that has sometimes hundreds of phpcs errors - it is not pragmatic to fix all the phpcs errors in these files **right now**. One example is a file full of functions that don't have [doc comments](http://www.phpdoc.org/). Another example is if a class name starts with a lowercase letter an error is thrown but fixing this might involve changing 10, 20+ files which would need need committing which would then be sniffed, recurse...
3. We have some files that are a bit large (e.g. 4000 lines of code?) and phpcs takes several minutes to check them. Delaying the commit by this long is unacceptable.
4. I haven't tested this yet but I imagine if you do a svn branch and commit it, phpcs will check everything and take a very long time to check all 1000 files?

Given that we can't refactor our whole codebase today - Does anyone know how I can use a svn commit parameter that will tell the svn pre-commit hook to not run phpcs?

Or perhaps there is another way to remove the headaches described?

Answer (score 2):

Why run it on a pre-commit?  I've used both [PHPUnderControl](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/about.html) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to automate php "builds"...  Basically, they run an ant/phing build script which runs the automated tests (PHPUnit) and code quality scanners (including PHPCS) after every commit (automatically detected).  So it won't reject the commit, but it will send a nice email to whomever you want that the build failed and list why (the specific lines of offending code)...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Good idea I will look into continuous integration... I never considered it could be useful for a non-compiled language.

Comment: I find it VERY useful.  Especially since we've started to venture into Selenium testing.  Basically, it's setup to run the entire test/build/documentation cycle on each commit, and if it passes it packages and pushes to a central server.  So that server will always have the most recent passing build on it (including documentation, etc).  It makes managing and interacting with a team FAR easier when utilizing any kind of Agile methodology...

Answer (score 2):

We have found the following works well, balancing the need to get code in without fuss, but preventing releases that diverge from our standards.

First, we have an "open arms" policy on commit:

- All code, working or not, conforming or not, accepted: so long as its commit log message has a bug tracking ID (pre-commit hook check)
- Encourages frequent commits & its benefits: collaboration, undo, backup

Then, we have a "clenched fist" policy on staging/release builds:

- Build fails if any, even trivial, deviation from rules, which means:
  mandatory syntax correctness, standards compliance, code
  documentation, and all tests pass with flying colors
- Prevents releasing anything buggy.  If something buggy does get
  through, it's a problem with the code AND a problem with the build
  (process hole, not enough tests, etc.)

All of that is automated through phing using phpcs (and of course phpunit, phpdocumentor, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think `ircmaxell` has a excellent point - this kind of standards checking should be somewhere other than a pre-commit hook, e.g. in a continuous integration envioronment or at a pinch, a post-commit hook and should be based around *information providing* rather than blocking commits!

Bearing this in mind, I decided *for the moment*, to use an *opt-in* approach. I configured the svn pre-commit hook to look in the commit message for a keyword and run `phpcs` if it was found.

In pre-commit hook script, e.g. `/var/www/svn/repos/<reponame>/hooks/`;

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
PHPCS=/usr/bin/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit

if [[ `$SVNLOOK log -t $TXN $REPOS | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"` =~ "\[?standardcode\]?" ]]; then

  # Run the PHP code sniffer                                                                                                                     
  PHPCS_STRICT=`$PHPCS "$REPOS" -t "$TXN"`
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "$PHPCS_STRICT" >>/dev/stderr
      echo "*** Commit blocked - Please fix coding standard errors." >>/dev/stderr
      exit 1
  fi
fi

exit 0
```

Notes:

- The keyword I chose was `[standardcode]` and the log message was converted to lowercase to make the keyword match case insensitive.
- The `phpcs` commit hook (`/usr/bin/scripts/phpcs-svn-pre-commit`) comes packaged with `phpcs` (at least in CentOS 5.5).

The idea is that a developer can choose to put the keyword in their commit message as a sort of badge of honour but they are not forced to have their code checked if it is not appropriate for their commit.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having a sniffer?  It's meant to enforce a style, not just check for it when asked to.  Besides, a later commit will fail on a prior commit if the prior one was bypassed...

Comment: @ircmaxell - yes it does. Our development process is evolving, I want to start with baby-steps in the right direction and improve it in time.

Comment: Well, that's quite fair.  Best of luck!